# How to update browser url when a property changes on a component?

Tags: angular

If I browse to `http:\\localhost:4300\fr`, my home page gets loaded with a french translation.

I have 2 links in my navigation (Home, Contact Us).

Home points to `http:\\localhost:4300\fr\home`
Contact Us points to `http:\\localhost:4300\fr\contact`

I also have a dropdown which in which the user can select a language and it will return the translated page.

For example, when I select Spanish, the links update to:

`http:\\localhost:4300\es\home` and `http:\\localhost:4300\es\contact`, but the browser url remains `http:\\localhost:4300\fr`.

How can I update the browser url?

Here is the code I am using when the user picks a language from the dropdown:

```
  translate(langCode, language) {
    const hostName = document.location.hostname.replace('www.', '');

    this.currentTrans = language;
    this.currentTransCode = langCode;
    this._caseService.GetCaseData(caseUrl,  langCode);
  }
```

`this.currentTransCode` holds the current language code

The url is contructed like this `http:\\localhost:4300\` + `this.currentTransCode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the location object

```
//component or service.ts
import {Location} from '@angular/common'

constructor(private location: Location)
{
}

changeCurrentUrl()
{
    let parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    parts[1] = this.currentTransCode; //replaces 'fr' with 'en'
    this.changeUrl(parts.join('/'));
}
 changeUrl(url: string)
 {
    this.location.replaceState(url);
 }
```

Comment: Great this worked.  If my current url is `http:\\localhost:4300\fr\contact`, how can I change it to `http:\\localhost:4300\es\contact`?  Right now, I am doing `this.location.replaceState('/' + this.currentTransCode) so no matter what page I am on it always translates to `http:\\localhost:4300\` + `this.currentTranscode`

Comment: I updated the answer with another method you can use for that

Answer (score 0):

To change the url, you need to load the page with the right language.
For example you can get the current pathname, and replace the language with the new one, and use the new url to reload the page.

```
document.location.href = "/" + this.currentTransCode + location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.indexOf("/",1)) + location.hash + location.search
```

### UPDATE:

Sorry, I miss you use Angular. In that case, you can use $location.

```
$location.path(newUrl);
```

You can get more details from here: https://www.consolelog.io/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/